# "chalice deploy" call ends up with "Unknown parameter in input: "Layers""

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-lambda, chalice

I create the most basic chalice app

```
from chalice import Chalice

app = Chalice(app_name='testApp')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return {'hello': 'world'}
```

with empty requirements.txt and config that looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "app_name": "testApp",
  "stages": {
    "dev": {
      "api_gateway_stage": "api"
    }
  }
}
```

Error fires right after the first deploy

This is the error i receive:

Creating deployment package.
Updating policy for IAM role: testApp-dev
Updating lambda function: testApp-dev
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\vic\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\chalice\cli__init__.py", line 466, in main
    return cli(obj={})
  File "c:\users\vic\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 722, in **call**
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\vic\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\users\vic\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "c:\users\vic\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\users\vic\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\vic\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 17, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\vic\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\chalice\cli__init__.py", line 202, in deploy
    deployed_values = d.deploy(config, chalice_stage_name=stage)
  File "c:\users\vic\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\chalice\deploy\deployer.py", line 342, in deploy
    return self._deploy(config, chalice_stage_name)
  File "c:\users\vic\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\chalice\deploy\deployer.py", line 355, in _deploy
    self._executor.execute(plan)
  File "c:\users\vic\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\chalice\deploy\executor.py", line 31, in execute
    self._default_handler)(instruction)
  File "c:\users\vic\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\chalice\deploy\executor.py", line 43, in _do_apicall
    result = method(**final_kwargs)
  File "c:\users\vic\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\chalice\awsclient.py", line 283, in update_function
    layers=layers
  File "c:\users\vic\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\chalice\awsclient.py", line 352, in _update_function_config
    max_attempts=self.LAMBDA_CREATE_ATTEMPTS
  File "c:\users\vic\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\chalice\awsclient.py", line 1009, in _call_client_method_with_retries
    response = method(**kwargs)
  File "c:\users\vic\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 314, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "c:\users\vic\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 586, in _make_api_call
    api_params, operation_model, context=request_context)
  File "c:\users\vic\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 621, in _convert_to_request_dict
    api_params, operation_model)
  File "c:\users\vic\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\validate.py", line 291, in serialize_to_request
    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:

Unknown parameter in input: "Layers", must be one of: FunctionName, Role, Handler, Description, Timeout, MemorySize, VpcConfig, Environment, Runtime, DeadLetterConfig, KMSKeyArn, TracingConfig, RevisionId

Comment: I am confused. How exactly are you deploying and what are you deploying? Lambda function? If so, the code is completely wrong.

Comment: I am deploying an app wich has one simple view that shout return {"hello": "world"} on route "/"

Comment: Is that a lambda function? And how are you deploying it? CloudFormation, SAM, through console?

Comment: I am deploying trough Chalice micro frame wich sets up the policies etc (https://github.com/aws/chalice). It has its own flow where it creates api and lambda under the hood

Comment: What region are you using to deploy the app?

Comment: I am using Us-west-2

Comment: That is strange, my guess is that there is something wrong with your local installation. I have tried the exact example and it worked.

Comment: Thank you @MatusDubrava for giving a shot! Beer is on me

Answer (score 0):

After troubleshooting found some issues with my local configurations. What helped was running the chalice in virtualenv (https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/)